# Early 2015 Macbook Pro Internal Keyboard isnt working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, battery, trackpad

Before i start, i replaced the battery on my macbook pro early 2015 model. I followed the instruction from ifixit to a T. When i went to turn the laptop on, the power button didnt do anything. I figured the new battery was dead so i went to plug it in and to my surprise the computer chimed at me simply from plugging it in... i had thought i had shut down completely before disassembly to install the new battery, but i guess not.

So now that the computer was on, it is asking for a password as if i was waking it up from sleep.. but none of the keys on my internal keyboard work. holding the power button doesnt do anything. The trackpad is working though.

I plugged in a USB keyboard from my PC and most of the keys on it wont work on the macbook (corsair k95 platinum). Some keys do work though, "Z","X", and "V" work but "C" doesnt. I should note here that i dont actually know what the working keys are mapped to because i am entering these keys in the password field to unlock the macbook.

Since the trackpad was working, i figured a system reboot might do the trick so i went to hit the shut down button only to have the system go into sleep mode. the restart button makes the computer enter sleep mode and exit it immediately.. or maybe i am just confused on what the system is actually doing.

Has anyone experienced this? How do i restart my computer without a power button or functional internal/external keyboard?

Lasts resort is to take it to the apple store but who knows what they will say since i replaced the battery without paying apple.

Also, while the magsafe plug does change color from green to amber, the mac os doesnt recognize that it is charging.. the icon never changes to a lightning bolt in the corner, but the battery percentage is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

So i unplugged everything and replugged everything back in and now it is working fine. i guess it is either a cable that is going bad or i didnt secure everything tightly.